# vector<T>::iterator - invalid?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [g++ “is not a type” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301380/g-is-not-a-type-error)

The following does not compile:

```
1    template<typename T>
2    void foo(std::vector<T>::iterator & i)
3    {  
4    }
```

On Visual Studio, I get the following errors:

```
>(2) error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
>(4) warning C4346: 'std::vector<_Tp>::iterator' : dependent name is not a type
     prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
>(4) error C2182: 'foo' : illegal use of type 'void'
>(4) error C2998: 'int foo' : cannot be a template definition
```

Comment: Found this [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301380/g-is-not-a-type-error), there are more but I cannot find them. :S

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` is a type that is *dependent* on a template parameter, namely `T`. Therefore, you should prefix with it `typename`:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(typename std::vector<T>::iterator & i)
{  
}
```

[Here's an explanation.](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html)

Comment: @Fred: I'm maxed so I'm shooting fast for accepted answers. :P

Comment: Haha, I shall accept your answer tomorrow then :) (so that you can get +15)

Comment: @Jacob: Accepted answers are immune to the limit: http://stackoverflow.com/faq